# JavaScript: converting NaN to 0

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working on a giant online time sheet for my company, using JavaScript to do calculations of each row in a total field.

Everything is working with numeric inputs, but if the user inserts a non-numeric value in one of the text boxes the total value will be: NaN error.

How can I change my JavaScript code so that if the user enters, for example, SYG in the textbox then it will count as 0?

Here's the entire script:

```
<script language="javascript">  
function addsum()

{
var man_1, man_2, man_3, man_4, man_5, man_6, man_7, man_8, man_9, man_10, man_11,  total_1;
var tir_1, tir_2, tir_3, tir_4, tir_5, tir_6, tir_7, tir_8, tir_9, tir_10, tir_11, tota l_2;
var ons_1, ons_2, ons_3, ons_4, ons_5, ons_6, ons_7, ons_8, ons_9, ons_10, ons_11, total_3;
var tor_1, tor_2, tor_3, tor_4, tor_5, tor_6, tor_7, tor_8, tor_9, tor_10, tor_11,  total_4;
var fre_1, fre_2, fre_3, fre_4, fre_5, fre_6, fre_7, fre_8, fre_9, fre_10, fre_11,   total_5;
var lør_1, lør_2, lør_3, lør_4, lør_5, lør_6, lør_7, lør_8, lør_9, lør_10, lør_11, total_6;
var søn_1, søn_2, søn_3, søn_4, søn_5, søn_6, søn_7, søn_8, søn_9, søn_10, søn_11, total_7;
var oa_1, oa_2, oa_3, oa_4, oa_5, oa_6, oa_7;

man_1 = Number(document.form1.man_1.value);
man_2 = Number(document.form1.man_2.value);
man_3 = Number(document.form1.man_3.value);
man_4 = Number(document.form1.man_4.value);
man_5 = Number(document.form1.man_5.value);
man_6 = Number(document.form1.man_6.value);
man_7 = Number(document.form1.man_7.value);
man_8 = Number(document.form1.man_8.value);
man_9 = Number(document.form1.man_9.value);
man_10 = Number(document.form1.man_10.value);
man_11 = Number(document.form1.man_11.value);
tir_1 = Number(document.form1.tir_1.value);
tir_2 = Number(document.form1.tir_2.value);
tir_3 = Number(document.form1.tir_3.value);
tir_4 = Number(document.form1.tir_4.value);
tir_5 = Number(document.form1.tir_5.value);
tir_6 = Number(document.form1.tir_6.value);
tir_7 = Number(document.form1.tir_7.value);
tir_8 = Number(document.form1.tir_8.value);
tir_9 = Number(document.form1.tir_9.value);
tir_10 = Number(document.form1.tir_10.value);
tir_11 = Number(document.form1.tir_11.value);
ons_1 = Number(document.form1.ons_1.value);
ons_2 = Number(document.form1.ons_2.value);
ons_3 = Number(document.form1.ons_3.value);
ons_4 = Number(document.form1.ons_4.value);
ons_5 = Number(document.form1.ons_5.value);
ons_6 = Number(document.form1.ons_6.value);
ons_7 = Number(document.form1.ons_7.value);
ons_8 = Number(document.form1.ons_8.value);
ons_9 = Number(document.form1.ons_9.value);
ons_10 = Number(document.form1.ons_10.value);
ons_11 = Number(document.form1.ons_11.value);
tor_1 = Number(document.form1.tor_1.value);
tor_2 = Number(document.form1.tor_2.value);
tor_3 = Number(document.form1.tor_3.value);
tor_4 = Number(document.form1.tor_4.value);
tor_5 = Number(document.form1.tor_5.value);
tor_6 = Number(document.form1.tor_6.value);
tor_7 = Number(document.form1.tor_7.value);
tor_8 = Number(document.form1.tor_8.value);
tor_9 = Number(document.form1.tor_9.value);
tor_10 = Number(document.form1.tor_10.value);
tor_11 = Number(document.form1.tor_11.value);
fre_1 = Number(document.form1.fre_1.value);
fre_2 = Number(document.form1.fre_2.value);
fre_3 = Number(document.form1.fre_3.value);
fre_4 = Number(document.form1.fre_4.value);
fre_5 = Number(document.form1.fre_5.value);
fre_6 = Number(document.form1.fre_6.value);
fre_7 = Number(document.form1.fre_7.value);
fre_8 = Number(document.form1.fre_8.value);
fre_9 = Number(document.form1.fre_9.value);
fre_10 = Number(document.form1.fre_10.value);
fre_11 = Number(document.form1.fre_11.value);
lør_1 = Number(document.form1.lør_1.value);
lør_2 = Number(document.form1.lør_2.value);
lør_3 = Number(document.form1.lør_3.value);
lør_4 = Number(document.form1.lør_4.value);
lør_5 = Number(document.form1.lør_5.value);
lør_6 = Number(document.form1.lør_6.value);
lør_7 = Number(document.form1.lør_7.value);
lør_8 = Number(document.form1.lør_8.value);
lør_9 = Number(document.form1.lør_9.value);
lør_10 = Number(document.form1.lør_10.value);
lør_11 = Number(document.form1.lør_11.value);
søn_1 = Number(document.form1.søn_1.value);
søn_2 = Number(document.form1.søn_2.value);
søn_3 = Number(document.form1.søn_3.value);
søn_4 = Number(document.form1.søn_4.value);
søn_5 = Number(document.form1.søn_5.value);
søn_6 = Number(document.form1.søn_6.value);
søn_7 = Number(document.form1.søn_7.value);
søn_8 = Number(document.form1.søn_8.value);
søn_9 = Number(document.form1.søn_9.value);
søn_10 = Number(document.form1.søn_10.value);
søn_11 = Number(document.form1.søn_11.value);

oa_1 = Number(document.form1.oa_1.value);
oa_2 = Number(document.form1.oa_2.value);
oa_3 = Number(document.form1.oa_3.value);
oa_4 = Number(document.form1.oa_4.value);
oa_5 = Number(document.form1.oa_5.value);
oa_6 = Number(document.form1.oa_6.value);
oa_7 = Number(document.form1.oa_7.value);



total_1 = man_1 + man_2 + man_3 + man_4 + man_5 + man_6 + man_7 + man_8 + man_9 + man_10 + man_11;
total_2 = tir_1 + tir_2 + tir_3 + tir_4 + tir_5 + tir_6 + tir_7 + tir_8 + tir_9 + tir_10 + tir_11;
total_3 = ons_1 + ons_2 + ons_3 + ons_4 + ons_5 + ons_6 + ons_7 + ons_8 + ons_9 + ons_10 + ons_11;
total_4 = tor_1 + tor_2 + tor_3 + tor_4 + tor_5 + tor_6 + tor_7 + tor_8 + tor_9 + tor_10 + tor_11;
total_5 = fre_1 + fre_2 + fre_3 + fre_4 + fre_5 + fre_6 + fre_7 + fre_8 + fre_9 + fre_10 + fre_11;
total_6 = lør_1 + lør_2 + lør_3 + lør_4 + lør_5 + lør_6 + lør_7 + lør_8 + lør_9 + lør_10 +  lør_11;
total_7 = søn_1 + søn_2 + søn_3 + søn_4 + søn_5 + søn_6 + søn_7 + søn_8 + søn_9 + søn_10 +           søn_11;
samlet_1 = man_1 + tir_1 + ons_1 + tor_1 + fre_1 + lør_1 + søn_1;
samlet_2 = man_2 + tir_2 + ons_2 + tor_2 + fre_2 + lør_2 + søn_2;
samlet_3 = man_3 + tir_3 + ons_3 + tor_3 + fre_3 + lør_3 + søn_3;
samlet_4 = man_4 + tir_4 + ons_4 + tor_4 + fre_4 + lør_4 + søn_4;
samlet_5 = man_5 + tir_5 + ons_5 + tor_5 + fre_5 + lør_5 + søn_5;
samlet_6 = man_6 + tir_6 + ons_6 + tor_6 + fre_6 + lør_6 + søn_6;
samlet_7 = man_7 + tir_7 + ons_7 + tor_7 + fre_7 + lør_7 + søn_7;
samlet_8 = man_8 + tir_8 + ons_8 + tor_8 + fre_8 + lør_8 + søn_8;
samlet_9 = man_9 + tir_9 + ons_9 + tor_9 + fre_9 + lør_9 + søn_9;
samlet_10 = man_10 + tir_10 + ons_10 + tor_10 + fre_10 + lør_10 + søn_10;
samlet_11 = man_11 + tir_11 + ons_11 + tor_11 + fre_11 + lør_11 + søn_11;
samlet_12 = total_1 + total_2 + total_3 + total_4 + total_5 + total_6 + total_7;
samlet_13 = oa_1 + oa_2 + oa_3 + oa_4 + oa_5 + oa_6 + oa_7;


document.form1.total_1.value = total_1;
document.form1.total_2.value = total_2;
document.form1.total_3.value = total_3;
document.form1.total_4.value = total_4;
document.form1.total_5.value = total_5;
document.form1.total_6.value = total_6;
document.form1.total_7.value = total_7;
document.form1.samlet_1.value = samlet_1;
document.form1.samlet_2.value = samlet_2;
document.form1.samlet_3.value = samlet_3;
document.form1.samlet_4.value = samlet_4;
document.form1.samlet_5.value = samlet_5;
document.form1.samlet_6.value = samlet_6;
document.form1.samlet_7.value = samlet_7;
document.form1.samlet_8.value = samlet_8;
document.form1.samlet_9.value = samlet_9;
document.form1.samlet_10.value = samlet_10;
document.form1.samlet_11.value = samlet_11;
document.form1.samlet_12.value = samlet_12;
document.form1.samlet_13.value = samlet_13;



}
```

Comment: kinda beautiful in its own way

Comment: Please show your html code also

Comment: I think you need to be introduced to the magical power of arrays

Comment: Arrays perhaps? - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: You are converting all of the values into a Number object so anything that isn't a proper numeric value will result in NaN.  In order to support conversion of characters into some value you will have to check each value to see if it contains 'SVG' and then place 0 in as the number.

Comment: Haha sorry guys , but i just startet html and php :/ getting it to work was hard enough. :)

Comment: I got a question more for yah :) Lets say that on monday the worker has more then 8 hours counted in the total field fx 10 hours for monday. I then want it to add the 2 overtime hours to $ao_1Field.

Answer (score 1):

To JUST answer your question and not try to fix this highly inefficient script, change

```
man_1 = Number(document.form1.man_1.value)
```

To

```
man_1 = getNumber(document.form1.man_1.value);
```

And add

```
function getNumber(str) {
  return isNaN(str)|| str==null?0:Number(str);
}
```

And repeat for all the other days

But please look into arrays

I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/VSGsL/) containing the following code which I cannot debug because I only have an iPad at the moment

```
var days = "man,tir,ons,tor,fre,lør,søn".split(",");
window.onload=function() {
  var content=document.getElementById("content");
  for (var i=0;i<days.length;i++) {
    content.innerHTML += '<br/>'+days[i]+'<br/>';
    for (var j=1;j<=11;j++) {
      content.innerHTML+='<input type="text" name="'+days[i]+"_"+j+'" onkeyup="total(this)"/>';
    }
    content.innerHTML+='<input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="total_'+(i+1)+'"/>';
  }
  content.innerHTML += '<br/>oa<br/>';
  for (var i=0;i<days.length;i++) {
    content.innerHTML+='<input type="text" name="oa_'+(i+1)+'"/>';
  }
  content.innerHTML += '<br/>samlet<br/>';
  for (var i=1;i<=13;i++) {
    content.innerHTML+='<input type="text" name="samlet_'+i+'"/>';
  }
}
function total(fld) {
  var form=fld.form,tot=0,sam=0,oa=0;
  for (var tot=0,i=0;i<days.length;i++) {
    for (var day=0,j=1;j<=11;j++) {
      day=getNum(form.elements[days[i]+'_'+j].value);
      tot+=day;
      form.elements["samlet_"+j].value=getNum(form.elements["samlet_"+j].value)+day;
    }
    form.elements["total_"+(i+1)].value=tot;
    var oaTot=tot>8?tot-8:0;
    var thisOa = getNum(form.elements["oa_"+i].value)+oaTot;
    sam+=tot;
    oa+=thisOa;;
  }
  form.elements["samlet_12"].value=sam;
  form.elements["samlet_13"].value=oa;
}
function getNum(str) {
  return str==null || str=="" || isNaN(str)?0:Number(str);
}
```

Comment: There wasn't an error produced, however you had content += '<br/>'+days[i]+'<br/>'; which should have been content.innerHTML += '<br/>'+days[i]+'<br/>'; - http://jsfiddle.net/VSGsL/11/

Comment: Thank you for the kind help, this is my first html page and useing php so , im kinda useing what ever i can read on the net. il check it out :)

Comment: your `getNumber` can be made more efficient like this: `return Number(str)||0`

Comment: Will that handle blank and isNaN ?

Comment: I do mate... I got a question more for yah :) Lets say that on monday the worker has more then 8 hours counted in the total field fx 10 hours for monday. I then want it to add the 2 overtime hours to $ao_1Field.

Comment: So if the value in Total_1Field is greater then 8 fx (10) it will show 10 hours in total_1Field but also show 2 hours in oa_1Field.

Comment: Sure. I did not see oa was "overarbejde" - I'll look later. I am losing my wifi in 30 min- see update which again I could not debug and am not 100%sure is in the place you wanted

Comment: Cool thank you , i think it it easyer to let u into the site so u can check it out to see what i mean. just go to http://www.jcnedrivning.dk/timeseddel/  use login jc and pass 7100 and u will see

Comment: im still useing the old code i posten up 2 , but with the code u typed to give letters a value of 0

Comment: Please look in the console. I have no way to debug for another week